# Issue connecting alexa with facebook

Tags: facebook, alexa-skills-kit

I followed instructions from this page
http://matchboxmobile.com/blog/oauth-using-alexa/

I configured facebook login page with valid oauth url as below
http://matchboxmobile.com/blog/oauth-using-alexa/

Redirect url in fb
https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/M1IGC7U465K7PQ

app id / client id is : 386368825105565

In developer console,
Access Token URI
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token

whenever I hit the following url ==>
Authorization uri
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=386368825105565&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/M1IGC7U465K7PQ

I am getting {message null}.

Even from my skill it is not connecting to facebook.
My question is about How to Fix it and make it connect to facebook?

Comment: Don’t understand what you mean, _where_ exactly are you getting “{message null}”? When I follow that URL, the Facebook login dialog pops up as expected, and asks me for permissions …

Comment: after login I am getting {message null}

Comment: So that would then likely be the part where your app exchanges the code for an access token. But figuring out what actually goes wrong in that place would require some debugging, checking what parameters are actually send to the API and how it responds ... can’t help you with that, not familiar with Alexa and what services Amazon offers around it.